# How not to return select statements in SQL Server stored procedure if there is raiseerror below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, raiserror

Is it possible in SQL Server some way not to return select statements in stored procedure if there is raiseerror or throw below?

I have select statement, and if the row count is bigger than some number, I raiseerror. In my application I use ado.net, and so error is in second result ( I must do NextResult(), so before it I must process my first result). Is it possible to know if there is second result or not? Or is it possible not to return select ? Or how either can I solve this problem: not to process select if its rows count is bigger than some particular number?

Comment: `select` statements have no side effects, so there is nothing to undo.

Comment: yes, I mean not to return that select in sp result

Comment: Do you mean that if you have `SELECT 1; SELECT 0/0` to not return the first dataset? Like @GordonLinoff said, you can't "undo" a dataset. If you want to discard that dataset in the event of an error handle the error in your application.

Comment: @Larnu : Yes I mean not to return the first select. And I can't it handle in applicatin, because before seeing that it is error in secod result, I must process first select, which is heavy operation.

Comment: If the second result set is prone to error, then do that one first?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: Otherwise, the only other thing I can think of is to put all your datasets into temporary tables, then return those datasets after all the datasets in the SP have been processed. If you've got a a lot of datasets, or very large datasets, that could have (serious) performance implications. Doing the discarding in the application is the "correct" choice here (in my opinion).

Comment: Perhaps you want a stored function and not a stored procedure.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: No I need stored procedure

Comment: (Not to be rude but) you don't seem to be very open to suggestion here. If you can't change your application, or object, then what *can* you do? It seems like you're wanting a functional change to SQL Server itself, rather than changing your application to work with known functionality of SQL Server. You might want to consider expanding your question to explain your actual goal (as at the moment it's unclear and only explained in the comments), and then how *you* want to achieve your goal and limitations you're facing. Not being able to change your object or application are big limitations.

Comment: @Larnu: (not to be rude) But your suggestions are obisious and useless if I can change places of select statetements or handle it in my application I didn't write these question. i use ADO.net and if I can somewhre to know if there is second result before moving to nextresult() it will be good solution, otherwise I had to use table variable to store result

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check how many rows a statement will return without it being run, no. If you have a (simple) statement like `SELECT * FROM MyTable1 MT1 JOIN MyTable2 MT2 on MT1.ID = MT2.fID;` until that statement is run, SQL Server won't know how many rows will be returned.

If you, however, don't want to return that dataset if it has more the *x* rows, you could use a `IF` statement:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable1 MT1 JOIN MyTable2 MT2 on MT1.ID = MT2.fID) <= 1024 BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable MT1
         JOIN MyTable MT2 ON MT1.ID = MT2.fID;

    SELECT ... --Your other SELECT statement
END ELSE BEGIN
    RAISERROR(...
END
```

If there are more than 1024 rows, then no dataset will be returned. This option will (probably) be less costly than a process like inserting all your data into a temporary table, especially if you're working with a large dataset. If you're inserting everything into a temporary table, then **every** row needs to be read and written to tempdb, and then read back when you return the data at the end of your statement(s); that's not a cheap operation with a lot of data.

Comment: Thanks, I also think about this solution. But in this case I must run my query  twice, and it's heavy query with many joines and conditions

Comment: @AramGevorgyan There's not a lot you can really do. This is why I was suggesting handling it in your application. If that's not an option, then you're forcing your hand into a less ideal solution, which means running parts of the query more than once.

Comment: I use ado.net if there is way to know if there is second result without loseing the first one, I'll handle it in my application

Comment: @AramGevorgyan, SQL Server streams results back to the application serially so subsequent messages and result sets are behind the first one and not available until the first is consumed by the app. Your only options are to run the query twice, use the temp table approach Gordon mentioned, or handle it in your app code instead of T-SQL.

Comment: So, is your logic (in pseudo logic) `Perform SELECT statement1; IF Statement1.Rows > x {RaiseError. Exit} Perform SELECT Statement2. Exit`? Otherwise, why would you not have 2 result sets returned, unless an error occurs (and then that should be handled in the application). @DanGuzman it was i that suggested about the temp tables. However, thanks for confusing me with Gordan. ;)

Comment: No, no my logic is  is: if statement1.Rows > x RaiseError else select statement1 exit.      In ideal I want something like that.  And thanks you at any case for trying understand and help)

Comment: @AramGevorgyan if that's the logic you want, then what I've got above will give you that functionality.

Comment: Yes, as I see it's the only solution. I want ideal solution without not running the query twice. Because it's often used sp